# Hosting an asp website on EasyCgi

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, dotnetnuke

I have developed a website using ASP.NET/VB + SqlServer 2008 and Dotnetnuke CMS.
Now I have to host it on easycgi.com

I have some questions:

1. How should I restore my db (*unfortunately easycgi supports just sqlserver 2005*) so what should I do to convert my db to 2005?
2. and what should I do to host my website (*step-by-step "please"*).

Any help appreciated.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with easycgi but often times getting SQL Server can be a lot of work. If you can create a database at easycgi the best thing to do is script out your database in SQL server 2008 using this process [SQL Server 2008 script data](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2010/03/08/script-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

You'll then have everything for your database in a file.  It's scripted and then run that at easy cgi if they have a way to run scripts. Otherwise sometimes you can connect your SQL SErver management studio directly to your database there.

You'll get a temp URL probably at easycgi, make sure that is in PortalAlias table in your SQL Server database.

Update your web.config in two spots to connect to your new database, upload your files to the web server.

Again, never used easycgi, but hope this helps.